# How to rename/refactor variable in VSCode without getting alias `oldName as newName`

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, refactoring

VSCode has an option to change/rename variables called `editor.action.rename`, usually bound to <kbd>F2</kbd>.

However, in Typescript and Javascript, this uses aliases when renaming an imported variable, eg:

```
import { originalName } from 'my-package'
```

results in

```
import { originalName as newName } from 'my-package'
```

How to prevent this, and propagate the change to all references?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is possible to prevent renaming using aliases:

- open your settings file (JSON): <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`
- add the following lines

  ```json
  "javascript.preferences.useAliasesForRenames": false,
  "typescript.preferences.useAliasesForRenames": false,
  ```

Comment: But still... Related references don't change.

Comment: @p__d for me they do. And it opens the changed files

Comment: Is it possible to make it still use aliases when the symbol lives under node_modules? I keep accidently renaming things that live in node modules without realizing it until the automated build breaks or I run `pnpm i -f`.

Comment: @ChristopherHaws I was under the assumption that files ignored by git wouldn't be picked up but would be aliased. I see now that is not the case. I have no solution for this. Might be wise to file an issue in the VSCode repository.